# Return multiple images stored in database from asp.net core web api to be shown in carousel/scrollview

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui-angular2, ngx-bootstrap

I am reading multiple images stored in a table and returning list of array bytes from the asp.net core web api get method so that it can be shown in ngx bootstrap carousel/kendo ui scrollview in my angular project. What will be the best way to read these the bytes and provide to the array for the display in carousel?

Comment: Your question is *far* too broad. You cannot return multiple images at once. Each must be returned as a separate response in order to be reference as an image in your HTML. That means you need some sort of endpoint that can take a specific image reference, fetch that from the database, and return the data.

Comment: I can return list of array bytes from my web api right. How can I read them and set my array of carousel for it to work.

Comment: You can return a byte array, technically, but what you're actually returning is a `FileResult` composed from that byte array, which will write the bytes to the response body (*bytes*, mind you, not an array at that point) along with a `Content-Type` header indicating the mime type of the type those bytes represent (i.e. image/jpeg). You can only return *one* image, though. If you tried to do something like return the bytes of all the images all crammed in one byte array, the image itself would be invalid, and wouldn't actually be able to function as an image.

Comment: You only get one bite at the response apple. It must be a single resource, whether that be an HTML document or an image. You cannot return multiple of anything, image or not.